# "Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file" Error

Tags: java, api, telegram

i'm using badoualy api for telegram and ive compiled and made a jar of full classes all in one jar file.
now when im trying to use in a simple code it gaves me such an error:

"java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file com/github/badoualy/telegram/api/TelegramApp"

i dont know how to solve this problem.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Did you downloaded library?

Comment: yes from github and extracted the source nd compiled it into a jar library, but this error kills me